# ItemSelectedListener always calls position 0

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-spinner

I'm having a very strange thing happening.  So I have a listview that has two different types of rows.  One type of row has four spinners in it.  Everything with the listview works fine, unless there's only a couple of items in the list then the spinner won't select any items.  At first I thought this was an issue with the listview updating, but on further inspection the position for OnItemSelectedListener is always coming up as 0 no matter what item I select.  I've searched far and wide through google and stackoverflow and nothing seems to fix it.

Part of my getView() method inside my listview adapter

```
        mAdapter = new MathSpinnerAdapter(this.context, R.layout.spinner_entry, stringList);



        final Scan_Answers answer = getItem(position);
        final TextView sectionNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.questionNumber);
        sectionNumber.setText("Section " + answer.section_number + " - Question " + answer.answer_id);




            ImageView answerImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerPic);
            answerImage.setImageBitmap(answer.getAnswer_image());



        final Spinner answerA = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerA);
        final Spinner answerB = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerB);
        final Spinner answerC = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerC);
        final Spinner answerD = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerD);
        answerA.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        answerB.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        answerC.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        answerD.setAdapter(mAdapter);



        if(answer.getNewValue() != null && !answer.getNewValue().isEmpty()) {
            String a, b, c, d;
            a = answer.getNewValue().substring(0, 1);
            b = answer.getNewValue().substring(1, 2);
            c = answer.getNewValue().substring(2, 3);
            d = answer.getNewValue().substring(3, 4);
            answerA.setSelection(mAdapter.getPosition(a),false);
            answerB.setSelection(mAdapter.getPosition(b),false);
            answerC.setSelection(mAdapter.getPosition(c),false);
            answerD.setSelection(mAdapter.getPosition(d), false);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        int count = 0;

        answerA.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                answer.setNewValue(answerA.getSelectedItem().toString() + answerB.getSelectedItem().toString() + answerC.getSelectedItem().toString() + answerD.getSelectedItem().toString());


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        answerB.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                answer.setNewValue(answerA.getSelectedItem().toString() + answerB.getSelectedItem().toString() + answerC.getSelectedItem().toString() + answerD.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });


        answerC.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                answer.setNewValue(answerA.getSelectedItem().toString() + answerB.getSelectedItem().toString() + answerC.getSelectedItem().toString() + answerD.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        answerD.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                answer.setNewValue(answerA.getSelectedItem().toString() + answerB.getSelectedItem().toString() +      answerC.getSelectedItem().toString() +     answerD.getSelectedItem().toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });



    }
```

My spinner adapter

```
public class MathSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

ArrayList<String> list;
Context context;


public MathSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    list = objects;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_entry, parent, false);

    TextView label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);

    label.setText(list.get(position));


    return convertView;
}
}
```

I can't figure out why position is always 0 for onItemSelectedListener when there's only a couple of items in the listview.  Please help!

UPDATE:

I have removed the onItemSelectedListeners because they don't seem completely necessary and it's this line that is causing issues.

```
            answer.setNewValue(answerA.getSelectedItem().toString() + answerB.getSelectedItem().toString() + answerC.getSelectedItem().toString() + answerD.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

it's strange because all I'm doing is concatenating all the spinners together and setting it to a String value in Scan_answers.  I'm still trying to figure it out, I'll update if I figure out why

UPDATE 2:

So I think this may be related to [getSelectedItemPosition() of a spinner always returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137029/getselecteditemposition-of-a-spinner-always-returns-0)

this bug doesn't always happen in my case unless there's 3 or less items in my listview and it doesn't scroll  a lot.

Comment: Can you post your entire getView(). Especially where position is defined in `final Scan_Answers answer = getItem(position);`

Comment: You also never add anything to your adapter. This seems strange.

Comment: position is sent into getView,  this is my whole getView function that deals with this set of rows.  Im setting convertview to a custom spinner xml.  I have an arraylist of strings getting passed into my adapter

Comment: Can you post a picture of the layout. I'm not understanding what you are doing and why you have adapters for each sounded.

Comment: I posted a row layout.  Basically I add the spinner values together by storing into newvalue in scan_answers.  The problem is arising from the setSelection being called.  It's only there to repopulate the spinners onscroll, but when there isn't enough to scroll it messes everything up and only lets the itemselectedlistener get position = 0.